# How to convert datzs into jason format using anularr 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to create a  json format like this

```
{
   "Description":"Godown1",
   "InCharge":1,
   "ContactNumber":"94965241256",
   "Address":"addressdetails",
   "RackDetails":[
      {
         "Description":"R1"
      },
      {
         "Description":"R2"
      },
      {
         "Description":"R2"
      }
   ]
}
```

but iam getting  a format like

```
{"Description":"Godown1","InCharge":"1","ContactNumber":"94965241256","Address":"addressdetails"}
{"Description":"R1"},{"Description":"R2"}
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can indent the result when you use stringify:

```
JSON.stringify(new RackList("myname"), null, 2)
```

where `2` is the indentation level.